# How to use python 3 as a build script in non-python travis configuration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, travis-ci

I'm trying to use [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) on a C library that uses custom python3-based build scripts.

When the repository gets built, it fails on `./configure` because configure uses Python 3, which isn't installed by default.

If I were building a Python project, I would use this in my `.travis.yml`:

```
python:
  - "3.4"
```

However, this doesn't seem to affect my repository because it is in C. (I tried running `which python3` and `python --version`, which reported that python 3 didn't exist and python 2.7 was in use instead.)

The build script that I tried:

```
language: c

python:
  - "3.4"
```

How can I have Python 3 available in Travis CI when my project is not a Python project?

Comment: Did you try consulting the "Build system information" in the build log as advised by [the docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/)?

Comment: @skeggse There's nothing in that section about Python, probably because this is a C project, not a Python project.

Comment: I have the same problem. Event the `before_install` way does not work for me. Did you find any other way to set the default Python version later?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to just install the needed python3 packages by adding a `before_install:` section of your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: Why `before_install` instead of `install`?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why you could not use `install`, but the travis docs suggest installing ubuntu packages during `before_install`: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Ubuntu-packages

Comment: Thanks! It works. I ended up also including `sudo: true` because I figured out part of this before your answer, but I'm not sure whether or not that was required for it to work.

Comment: I've accepted this because it works, but I would prefer a solution that doesn't require switching away from the container-based infrastructure, if anyone has one.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use the container based infrastructure you can make use of the [apt addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Adding-APT-Packages):

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - deadsnakes # source required so it finds the package definition below
    packages:
      - python3.5
```

Packages that can be used are [listed here](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu-precise)

**Update**

In order to use dependencies with c-extensions like psycopg2 or pyYAML it is also necessary to add `python3.4-dev`

Comment: That's great, but how do I use it? It doesn't seem to be added to the path (calling python3 doesn't work, neither does python3.5)

Comment: That's odd, we install python3.4 and calling it works just fine.
Here the yml: https://github.com/crate/crate/blob/0.56/.travis.yml#L49
Here the usage: https://github.com/crate/crate/blob/0.56/blackbox/bootstrap.sh#L5

Answer (score 6):

Travis uses [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage its Python, and has both Python 2.7.16 and 3.6.3 installed by default at the time of writing. You can use `pyenv global 3.6` to use Python 3.6.3; you don't need root for this.

This is the easiest and fastest way to get a Python 3 and useful in cases where you don't require a specific Python 3 version (e.g. for a build script or the like). If you want specific Python versions and/or a build matrix then installing it as a package or addon as mentioned in some of the other answers is probably faster and easier.

Comment: The problem comes when pyenv doesn't have the version you need, then you need to finagle a janky solution to install that version with pyenv

Comment: @smac89 Any example on how to install a new version with pyenv on Travis?

Comment: @BorisDalstein `pyenv install 3.8.4`, then `pyenv global 3.8.4`. Honestly, I would drop pyenv and go with this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660551/2089675)

Comment: @smac89 Thanks, I had tried `pyenv install -v 3.7.7` (and others) but it complained that the python version wasn't available. `pyenv install --list | grep 3.7` returned nothing. I will try the other method using the deadsnakes PPA as you suggest, pyenv on Travis is driving me crazy at the moment...

Comment: @smac89 Follow up: at the end of the day, I did use pyenv rather than the deadsnakes PPA, but had to update pyenv first so that it can find Python 3.7. See my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083018/1951907). Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Yeah, my use case was that I just needed *a* Python 3 for a fairly simple build script for a project that otherwise doesn't use Python @smac89; using pyenv to manage your build matrix is a lot of hassle, and installing a package/addon is easier in those cases. I'll amend the answer to prevent confusion 

Answer (score 3):

The answer of mfussenegger is the recommended way to install stuff nowadays, however `deadsnakes` packages don't provide links for `python3` it seems, only for `python3.*`. You would use it if you require a recent python 3 release. Current travis builds on Ubuntu LTS 12.04, which comes with python 3.2, which is enough for most scripting purposes.

`python 3.*` is a problem when firing up a script with a shebang, where we can't include arbitrary name checks. That's why you probably still want the `python3` package, as in Eric Appelts answer:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, my C++ CMake project failed to correctly find the python libs for linking when installing python3.7 and python3.7-dev from deadsnakes.

What worked was to use pyenv, but on the Ubuntu Xenial dist provided by Travis, the shipped version of pyenv was too old and didn't have Python 3.7 available. What I had to do is to update pyenv first:

```
  install:
    - PYENV_VERSION=1.2.20
    - PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.8
    - pushd $(pyenv root)
    - git fetch
    - git checkout v$PYENV_VERSION
    - pyenv install -v $PYTHON_VERSION
    - popd
  before_script:
    - pyenv global $PYTHON_VERSION
    - PYTHON_PREFIX=$(python-config --prefix)
    - PYTHON_XY=python${PYTHON_VERSION%.*} # X.Y.Z -> pythonX.Y
    - CMAKE_EXTRA_ARGS+=" -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$PYTHON_PREFIX/bin/$PYTHON_XY"
    - CMAKE_EXTRA_ARGS+=" -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$PYTHON_PREFIX/lib/lib${PYTHON_XY}m.so"
    - CMAKE_EXTRA_ARGS+=" -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$PYTHON_PREFIX/include/${PYTHON_XY}m"
  script:
    - cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ${CMAKE_EXTRA_ARGS}
    - make
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me (on `bionic`):

```yaml
dist: bionic
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - deadsnakes
    packages:
      - python3.7
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal
  - sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools
  - pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

See it yourself: [.travis.yml](https://github.com/yegor256/xembly/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Answer (score 0):

#### Overview

- A cleaner, more modular approach is to use a `.python-version` configuration file [1] rather than having to directly specify the Python version in the Travis configuration file via the `pyenv global 3.6` command.
- e.g. I successfully installed and used `yamllint` with **Python 3.6.9** in my **Node.js** project.

#### Solution Details

- In the root directory of your project, create a `.python-version` and specify the python `3.6` alias as it's contents.

  - When using the **bionic** distribution, Travis will resolve `3.6` to it's default 3.6 Python installation
  - e.g. `3.6.9` [2]
- Optionally, do the following in your Travis configuration file:

  - (a) Instruct Travis to cache any Python packages between builds via the `cache` syntax
  - (b) Upgrade the default version of **pip** that comes with **Python 3.6.9**.
  - (c) Install **yamllint** as a global package

    - Note: It must be globally installed when the `language` is not `python` [3].

#### .python-version

```
3.6
```

#### .travis.yml

```yaml
dist: bionic
language: node_js
cache:
  pip: true
before_install:
  # Upgrade pip
  - python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade pip
  # Install yamllint
  - pip install --quiet --user yamllint
```

#### Resources

- [1] https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#choosing-the-python-version
- [2] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/bionic/#python-support
- [3] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#pip